# логирование ошибок в multi_query() для каждого подзапроса

Tags: php, логирование

Идет выборка данных, затем посредством цикла `while()` формируются запросы для некоторых пользователей в БД. Записываются в `$query`.

Как правильно использовать `mysqli_next_result()`, `mysqli_more_results()` чтобы логировать ошибку для каждого подзапроса при ее возникновении?

> mysqli_multi_query
>   Возвращает FALSE, если первое выражение вызвало
>   ошибку. Чтобы получить доступ к ошибкам остальных подзапросов, нужно
>   сначала вызвать функцию mysqli_next_result().

```
 // срабатывает логирование только для первого запроса

    if ($mysqli -> multi_query($query))
    {
        do
        {
            if (! empty($mysqli -> error))
                logMySQLError($mysqli -> error);
        }
        while ($mysqli -> next_result());
    }
    else
        logMySQLError($mysqli -> error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понять, какие по счёту запросы вызвали ошибки можно так:

```
<?php

$c = 0;
if($mysqli->multi_query(implode(';', $q))) {
    do {
        /*// Если запросы возвращают результаты - обрабатываете их
        if ($result = $mysqli->use_result()) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
              $row;
            }
        }
        */

        $c++;

        if(!$mysqli->more_results()) break; // Все запросы обработаны

        if(!$mysqli->next_result() || $mysqli->errno) {
            // report error
            $err[$c] = $mysqli->error;
        }
    } while(true);
}
else
    $err[$c] = $mysqli->error;
```

Comment: `Вы не должны пытаться выполнить оставшиеся запросы после ошибки.` - почему не должен? 5 уникальных запросов для 5-30 пользователей, всего 25-150 запросов. Мне необходимо выполнить все и если несколько из них дали сбой, я смогу выполнить их позже, вручную, вытащив из лога данные запроса.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать строку `break; // goto free`

Comment: строка: `$result->free_result();` выдает: `Fatal error: Call to a member function free_result() on boolean` Так понимаю в моем случае строку  требуется убрать как и `if ($result = $mysqli->use_result()) {` так как запрос не выводит какие-либо результаты.

Comment: Если вы не селекты делаете - всю ветку с fetch нужно удалить)

Comment: А как правильно описать словами работу цикла? Условие `while(true)` выполняется до тех пор, пока в `do` не сработает условие с `break` после этого прекращается работа. По сути нет разницы что передавать внутри `while`, он будет срабатывать при любом условии `while(true)`, `while(false)`, `while(26493)`?

Comment: Это называется бесконечный цикл) В вашем случае можно написать `while($mysqli->more_results()){...}`

Comment: При `while(false)` он завершится после первой итерации.